# Writing a script to automate npm command

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation

I am working on an angular js project and I would like to automate The following two commands.

```
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start
```

The issue is that I am working on a small angular project on github. I added all dependencies required to my package.json, However when my friend pulled it from git he was able to install protractor but he could not get webdriver to start unless he ran the above two commands. So i wanted to write some script to automate it and better yet even add `protractor  ./conf.js` to it.

So I did research and I am aware that I can write a npm script but I was not able to find a proper document that showed where to write the script and how to execute it. I would appreciate all suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `scripts` property to your package.json with the command you wish you run.

```
"scripts": {
  "prostart": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start",
  "proupdate": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update"
}
```

you would then run these by typing `npm run prostart` or `npm run proupdate` which would look for those commands in your package.json.

Comment: Would you run it using npm like "npm update" and "npm start" ??

Comment: npm update will update all dependencies I think so maybe it is better to use another word instead.

Comment: Agreed. I would name them more appropriately. Additionally you can use `&&` to concatenate the two commands if they are always run together in a particular order.

Comment: so something like this ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start ?

Comment: Yes that is it, @Dinero. Although, as you mention start/update should probably be renamed to something more specific.

Comment: npm ERR! testap@0.0.0 driverstart: `./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdr
iver-manager start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the testap@0.0.0 driverstart script.

Comment: I got an error actually and i named mine to driverstart, so i did npm run driverstart

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Josh's answer, the script `start` could be run as `npm start` as `start` is a special keyword, but `update` should be run as `npm run update` because `npm update` is another npm command entirely.

For any other command besides `start` and `test` (**I think**), you have to preface it with `npm run ...`